# WPF toolkit, shared tooltip between multiple lineseries

Tags: wpf, charts, tooltip, wpftoolkit

I'm working with multiple time-series chart based on WPF toolkit. For example time-series of temperature, dewpoint and pressure in one chart

I need to share tooltips to show at each datapoint a summary of the meteorlogical parameters at a certain date/time in a little tooltip frame.

If anyone know if it is possible and how to do that, it would be great.

Thanks,
PY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up `Styles` for the `DataPoints` of your Series i've got one example for `BubbleDataSeries`:

```
<Style x:Key="BubbleToolTipTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type c:BubbleDataPoint}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="c:BubbleDataPoint">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Size}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentControl Content ="{TemplateBinding DependentValue, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToStringConverter}}" />
                            <ContentControl Content ="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}"/>
                            <ContentControl Content ="{TemplateBinding Size}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```